# Superlative of tired

Tags: word-request, superlatives

Is the a superlative of the word "tired"? I mean, you can say "you look very good" or say "you look superb".
 How can I say "I'm *_word here_*" instead of "I'm very tired"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Protip: 'Superlative' generally refers to things such as 'best', 'worst', 'hottest', 'most strange')

There are various stronger synonyms you could use such as 'exhausted', 'shattered', (UK) 'knackered'. A little more colourfully you can say 'I'm dead on my feet.'

Comment: fyi - you'd probably not hear either 'shattered' or 'knackered' in US english.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I say "I'm *word here*" instead of "I'm very tired"?

A good choice is "I'm exhausted".

---

Other possibilities:

> "I'm bushed"

adjective
Informal. exhausted; tired out:
After all that exercise, I'm bushed.

> "I'm beat"

adjective
Informal. exhausted; worn out.

---

For whatever reason, I personally don't favor those, and would just use variations on "exhausted" such as "totally/completely __"